# top coins with i\use of tabs and spaces error in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, system

i try to make top to coins and i have error with tab and the code look to me good...

my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        with open('coins.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        leader_board = {}
        total = []
        for member in users:
            name = int(member)
            xp = users[str(member)]['coins']
            leader_board[xp] = name
            total.append(xp)

        total = sorted(total, reverse=True)

        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Top 10", color=random.choice(colors))
        index = 1
        for xp in total:
            id_ = leader_board[xp]
            member = await bot.fetch_user(id_)
            name = member.name
            embed.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}", value=f"{round(xp)} Coins",  inline=False)
            if index == 10:
                break
            else:
                index += 1
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        chat = ctx.channel
        if chat.id == 868869373383811102:
            with open('coins.json', 'r') as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            leader_board = {}
            total = []
            for member in users:
                name = int(member)
                xp = users[str(member)]['coins']
                leader_board[xp] = name
                total.append(xp)

            total = sorted(total, reverse=True)

            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Top 10", color=random.choice(colors))
            index = 1
            for xp in total:
                id_ = leader_board[xp]
                member = await bot.fetch_user(id_)
                name = member.name
                embed.add_field(name=f"{index}. {name}", value=f"{round(xp)} Coins",  inline=False)
                if index == 10:
                    break
                else:
                    index += 1
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            if chat.id != 868869373383811102:
                bob = await ctx.send("NOPE")
                await time.sleep(5)
                await bob.delete()
```

the error:
File "/home/container/main.py", line 442
bob = await ctx.send("NOPE")
^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

its 3.8 python

Comment: Try de-indenting the block at line 442 then indenting it again using whatever you used to indent the code initially (either tabs or spaces, not both at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Try de-indenting the block at line 442 then indenting it again using whatever you used to indent the code initially (either tabs or spaces, not both at the same time)
if you're using something like replit they have bugs where sometimes the code will just not work and that's why I recommend using your pc for running code.